# In rake how do I call a subdir Rakefile

Tags: ant, rake, jruby

In ant I'd do the following

```
 <target name="subclient" >
     <ant antfile="suddir/build.xml" target="target1" useNativeBasedir="true"/>
 </target>
```

How do I do this sort of thing in JRuby/Rake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `Dir.chdir` and launch a rake subprocess:

```
def rake(*args)
  ruby "-S", "rake", *args
end

task :subrake do
  Dir.chdir("subproject") do
    rake
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem called [rake-subproject](https://github.com/michaeljbishop/rake-subproject) that can help you with this:

With this in place, let's pretend your subproject is in a directory: 'foo'. You can simply add these lines to your Rakefile:

```
require 'rake/subproject'

subproject 'foo'
```

Now, you have all the tasks in 'foo:task' available to you and you can reference them via: `foo/<task name>` or `foo:<task name>task`

Disclosure: I am the author of this gem.